# Произвольное поле - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Помогите советом. Как сделать если значение доп.поля (id_626) равно Москва, выводить текст, если нет скрыть.

Comment: `print(get_post_meta($post->ID, "id_626", true) == "Москва" ? "Текст":"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php //проверяем, что есть такое поле с нужным значением
if (get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'id_626' ) === 'Москва') {
//выводим значение на экран
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'id_626', true );
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$town = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'id_626', true );

if ( $town == 'Москва' ){
  echo $town;
}
?>
```

Мой код похож на предыдущий, но у предыдущего ошибка. Он в `if` сравнивает с `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'id_626')`, которая без 3 параметра `true` в любом случае вернет массив и сравнение не пройдет никогда!